# Computing of time complexity of recursive function

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've understood how to compute the time and space complexity of algorithms, and I found an interesting problem for training.

```
// count the occurrence of an element in an array
// list is already sorted
function count (list, item, start, end) {
    if (start > end) {
        return 0;
    }
    const mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    if (list[mid] < item) {
        return count(list, item, mid + 1, end);
    }
    if (list[mid] > item) {
        return count(list, item, start, mid - 1);
    }
    return count(list, item, start, mid - 1) + 1 + count(list, item, mid + 1, end);
}
```

The answer is *O(n)*. I thought it should be something with a logarithm. Can somebody explain to me, why I'm wrong?

Comment: Hint: consider the worst case. For which input would this method take longest?

Comment: Oh, exactly! If each element in array will be the same, then time complexity will be _O(n)_. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where all elements of the list are equal to `item`. In this case you will only use first and last return. So you can write runtime of your algorithm for `n = end - start` as roughly:

```
T(n) = O(1) + 2 * T(n/2)
```

Which solves to `T(n) = O(n)`.

Comment: I'm right that average time complexity will be O(log n)?

Comment: @Sam, might be, depends on domain/distribution of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If we have n items all equal to the target, and we're counting them one by one:

```
... + 1 + ...
```

that's O(n) counts/calls at least.